# when to call view's GetParent method, how is view's life-cycle

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

when i call view's GetParent method in Constructor, it returns null. So where should i call this method to get the view`s parent.
thanks

Comment: I suggest adding some code so that we can see what you are trying to do. If you have set the content view, and then used findviewbyid for a child view it should work fine.

Comment: Can you show the code in the constructor. Maybe that way someone can determine the source of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns null because in the constructor the view doesn't have a parent yet. It gets the parent when you actually add the view to another view by doing addView(yourView); short example:

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
YourView yourView = new YourView(context); // yourView constructor gets called
layout.addView(yourView); // parent gets set to layout
```